# Scss grid grid-row: span from variable

Tags: css, css-grid, css-variables

I have a grid with horizontal and vertical header, in which the number of rows is dynamically sett by JS dependent on the content. Right now imp using css var which is set by JS. Is there more efficient way to set the grid? Is it possible to not use the `--rowCount` variable?

Sorry for there being a lot of code. I've tried to minimize it as much as possible.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 35px;
}

.vertical-header {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2/ span 5;
}

.horizontal-header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(15px, 1fr));
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(15px, 1fr));
  grid-column: 2;
}

.helper {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="helper"></div>
  
  <div class="vertical-header">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="horizontal-header">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="content">
    <div>yo</div>
    <div>yo</div>
    <div>yo</div>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div>yo</div>
    <div>yo</div>
    <div>yo</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

variable is used as:

```
--rowCount;
.vertical-header {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2/ span var(--rowCount);
}
```

Comment: Is the "Scss" in your title a typo?